# CMD: Получение даты создания файла

Tags: bat, cmd

Подскажите, как через командную строку получить дату **создания** файла для её последующей записи в текстовый файл?

Дата **изменения** меня не устраивает, но среди модификаторов даётся только она: %~t*имя_переменной*

`for %x in (*) do (echo %~nx %~tx >> F.txt)`

Сейчас есть мысль выводить дату через dir /tc в файл, потом его разбирать, отлавливая значения, и уже их снова выводить в итоговый файл.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, стал таки развивать эту мысль. Пришёл к такому результату:

```
dir folder\ /tc > dates.txt
set str=
for %x in (folder\*) do set str=!str!%~nx
findstr "%str%" < dates.txt > result.txt
```

Правда результат теперь и размеры файлов содержит, без них было бы идеально.

```
14.02.2015  18:08           131 072 f1
14.02.2015  18:08           262 144 f2
14.02.2015  18:10           393 216 f3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,2" %%a in ('dir') do @echo %%a %%b) > result.txt
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]