# Как узнать дату создания файла в bat?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, dos

Как можно узнать дату создания файла в BAT.
У `for` есть переменная `%%~ti`, но она указывает только на дату изменения файла. А как узнать именно дату создания файла?

Comment: Уже поднимался данный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/399487/cmd-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно получить с помощью WMIC:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set FileName=c:\Windows\notepad.exe
for %%a in ("%FileName%") do (
    set File=%%~fa
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ('wmic datafile where "name='!File:\=\\!'" get 'CreationDate' /format:csv ^| find /i "%ComputerName%"') do (set CreationDate=%%b)
    set cYear=!CreationDate:~0,4!
    set cMonth=!CreationDate:~4,2!
    set cDay=!CreationDate:~6,2!
    set cHour=!CreationDate:~8,2!
    set cMinutes=!CreationDate:~10,2!
    set TimeStamp=!cDay!.!cMonth!.!cYear! !cHour!:!cMinutes!
    ECHO !TimeStamp!
)
```

Вывод:

> 13.08.2015 22:39